# Copying values from another column with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, series

Am really new to this. I am trying to create a "Final Category" column primarily copying the values from column "Category 1" but there is a condition that if Category 1 is Financial but Category 2 is Real Estate, I have to copy Real Estate over instead.

I figured there should be a better condition statement than using this:

```
df[ (df.Category 1=='Financials') & (df.Category 2=='Real Estate') ]['Final Category'] = 'Real Estate'
```

[image]

Comment: What language/technology is this (tags would help)?

Comment: What is the issue with this code?

Comment: so I did a df.columns and realise the actual column names are: 中证\nCategory 1(Eng.) and 中证\nCategory 2(Eng.).  I amended the command to : df[ (df.中证\nCategory 1(Eng.)=='Financials') & (df.中证\nCategory 2(Eng.)=='Real Estate')] ['Final Category'] = 'Real Estate'   now the error is SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [avoid chained assignment](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy):

```
condition = df['Category 1'].eq('Financials') & df['Category 2'].eq('Real Estate')
df['Final Category'] = np.where(condition, 'Real Estate', df['Category 1'])
```

Comment: @newnew, No problem, if this answer helped feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left) so other users know.